# iOS 11.3 causes drawing canvas to pan/scroll with selection with Method-Draw / SVG-Edit

Tags: javascript, ios, svg, event-handling, svg-edit

We use [MethodDraw](https://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw) which is a fork of [SVG-Edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit). Ever since the last iOS update on the iPad or iPhone, the screen scrolls when you try to draw a line on the drawing canvas. When making a simple selection, the screen pans around making it unable to use. There is a [bug report](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/issues/227) on MethodDraw already, but it sounds like MethodDraw is no longer being maintained and updated.

To reproduce, view this page with a iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.3 or later: http://editor.method.ac/ and try to use the pencil to draw a line - you will see the screen move and it's almost impossible to use the app.

Searching the web for a solution, I found a similar issue but I'm still not sure how to patch MethodDraw to fix it. See webkit.org: [Bug 184250 - Unable to call event.preventDefault in dynamically added event
   listener](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184250)

I believe it has something to do with dynamic event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function we used to correct the problem. We call this function on page load.

```
function handleAppleDevice(){
    var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
    if(iOS){
        $('body').css('position','fixed');
    }
}
```